# How to pass JSON obj from jquery to PHP

Tags: json

I made a JSON object and stored it in a javascript vaiable and now I am trying to fetch the javascript variable value into a php variable but it is showing me error. Following is my code

```
 <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tp = [

                            {"Name" : "Abhimanyu", "Designation" : "Trainee Engineer"},
                            {"Name" : "Parag", "Designation" : "Trainee Engineer"}          

                ];

        var p = (tp[0]["Name"]);
        console.log(p);
        // alert(tp.names.Designation);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $c = $_GET['p'];
    echo "Value is " .$c;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not a JSON object. It's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation.

Comment: Where or how do you send the content of variable tp as p to your php script? The php script is executed server side and the javascript is executed at the client side. The value of p (client side) must be sent to the server in order to get processed.

Comment: how do i pass the value of p to the server ?